# The While statement fails the compare when using Bytes It seems it only takes int

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, int, compare, byte

II want to compare bytes in a video file.ser that has 8 bit data. I need to find the first non zero byte at the beginning of the frame. I use red = mm.read(1) to receive a byte direct from the file on disk because the files are huge.
I seems that While and if compare int data and fail to deliver the correct comparison when attempting to compare int(0) == b´\00 and Byte(0)==b´\00

"If" displayed the same effect and my attempt to redefine the variables as int have exceeded my knowledge.

```
mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0) #0=read the whole file
red = 0 #This value is int
print ("Red ",red) #Confirm int

while  red == 0:      # This works First time

    red = mm.read(1) # Now red is Byte 
    print ("Red = ",red, "Position  ", mm.tell(),"\r" ) #red is b´\x00
    red =red + 1# this fails as well 
else:
    print ("Red = ",red, "Position exit ", mm.tell() ) # exit because red is Byte
```

The first compare can only be True if both halves of the comparison are int. All other cases exit the while after one loop. PS.Further investigation reveals that (red +1) fails because of type discrepancies. This is likely because I do not know how to change or make them compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the type that was wrong now I have found

pixel = mm.read(1)

red = int.from_bytes(pixel,"little")

This gets the while loop working and will no doubt reveal the next issue. Since it is one byte "little" is probably not required but for the sake of completeness there it is.